# How can i find every functor from arguments?

Tags: prolog

With these facts:

```
   functor(a,b).
   functor(b,c).
   functor2(a,b).
   functor2(a,c).
```

Can i ask `findFunctor(F,a,b).` and get

```
   F = functor
   F = functor2
```

?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you using SWI:

```
find_functor(Functor, Args):-
 length(Args, Len),
 current_functor(Functor, Len),
 Functor \=':',   % Dismiss :/2 
 Term =.. [Functor|Args],
 predicate_property(Term, number_of_rules(0)),  % It's a fact
 \+ predicate_property(Term, imported_from(_)), % not from a module
 clause(Term, true).
```

and you can query

```
?- find_functor(Functor, [a,b]).
Functor = functor ;
Functor = functor2
```